Пишу тг бота на telebot, проблема с созданной базой данных

Как исправить красные символы? кодировка UTF-8 при преставление на другие кодировки нечего не меняется

Почему вы решили, что здесь какая-то проблема? Зачем вообще вы пытаетесь открывать базу в текстовом редакторе? Никто не обещал, что база будет открываться в текстовом редакторе

Мне нужно установить какое-то расширение?Хочу нормально просматривать бд

Ну, вбиваем в гyгл «просматривать бд sqlite» и получаем кучу вариантов на любой вкус. А зачем пытаться открывать бд в текстовом редакторе, непонятно

не получится посмотреть базу, как текстовый файл. Скачай прогу db browser или DBeaver
